# Using Python to compute the distance between coordinates (lat/long) using haversine formula and print results within .csv

Tags: python, gps, distance, latitude-longitude

I have a .csv file with 3 columns. The first column is titled Distance and it is empty. The second and third columns are titled Longitude and Latitude which contain coordinates, for example:

Distance,Longitude,Latitude

,-77.60483,40.31117

,-77.58167,40.3045

,-77.52883,40.24917

,-77.508,40.14917

,-77.49617,40.13117

I have wrote a script that computes the distance between the two points using the haversine formula (see below), but I have to manually enter the coordinates, which is not desirable:

```
import math

lat1 = 40.31117
long1 = -77.60483
lat2 = 40.3045
long2 = -77.58167

def distance_on_unit_sphere(lat1, long1, lat2, long2):

# Converts lat & long to spherical coordinates in radians.
degrees_to_radians = math.pi/180.0

# phi = 90 - latitude
phi1 = (90.0 - lat1)*degrees_to_radians
phi2 = (90.0 - lat2)*degrees_to_radians

# theta = longitude
theta1 = long1*degrees_to_radians
theta2 = long2*degrees_to_radians

# Compute the spherical distance from spherical coordinates.
# For two locations in spherical coordinates:
# (1, theta, phi) and (1, theta', phi')cosine( arc length ) =
# sin phi sin phi' cos(theta-theta') + cos phi cos phi' distance = rho * arc    length

cos = (math.sin(phi1)*math.sin(phi2)*math.cos(theta1 - theta2) +
   math.cos(phi1)*math.cos(phi2))
arc = math.acos(cos)*6371 #radius of the earth in km

return arc

print distance_on_unit_sphere(lat1,long1,lat2,long2)
```

My goal is to populate the empty distance column using Python by computing the distance between the 1st location (-77.60483,40.31117) and the 2nd location (-77.58167,40.3045) and then print that value into the Distance column and then compute the distance between the 2nd (-77.58167,40.3045) and 3rd point (-77.52883,40.24917) and then print that value below the previously computed value in Distance column and so on for the subsequent coordinates. I need some help or an example provided to input the .csv file, run the haversine formula, and then write the result into the appropriate location in an output .csv.

Comment: So which are the points that you want to calculate the distance within? Each row will have a point; Which should be the second point to be used for calculations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, this code should do what you're after.
Using your input

```
Distance,Longitude,Latitude
,-77.60483,40.31117
,-77.58167,40.3045
,-77.52883,40.24917
,-77.508,40.14917
,-77.49617,40.13117
```

I'm producing this output. I've assumed that you want the distances to go forward - i.e. that line 2 has its distance set to the distance to the next point (line 3).The last line is set to 0 as there is no following line to measure to

```
Distance,Longitude,Latitude
2.0992,-77.6048,40.3112
7.6122,-77.5817,40.3045
11.2593,-77.5288,40.2492
2.2399,-77.5080,40.1492
0.0000,-77.4962,40.1312
```

Keep your existing code, and append this snippet. The csv library makes it nice and easy to work with CSV files.

I'm also using a deque. This is a FIFO (first in, first out) data structure. I use this to keep a queue of points. Once this has two entries, I compute the distance between the two points, write it out, then discard the oldest point.

```
import csv
import collections
filein = open("test.csv","rU") # universal newline mode
fileout = open("output.csv","w")
fileout.write("Distance,Longitude,Latitude\n")
csvrdr = csv.reader(filein, delimiter=",")
linecount = 0
# use a deque. once this hits 2 entries, compute the distance
# and then remove the oldest entry
todo = collections.deque()
for line in csvrdr:
    if linecount > 0: # skip header
        _, longitude, latitude = line # _ means discard
        longitude = float(longitude)
        latitude = float(latitude)
        todo.append((longitude, latitude))
    if len(todo)==2:
        # got two points, compute distance and remove the oldest
        oldlon, oldlat = todo.popleft()
        distance = distance_on_unit_sphere(latitude, longitude, oldlat, oldlon)
        fileout.write("%2.4f,%2.4f,%2.4f\n" % (distance, oldlon, oldlat))
    linecount += 1
# got one entry in deque, spit that out with 0
assert(len(todo)==1)
oldlon, oldlat = todo.popleft()
fileout.write("%2.4f,%2.4f,%2.4f\n" % (0.0, oldlon, oldlat))
fileout.close()
filein.close()
```

Comment: I tried to append the snippet and have not been able to replicate your results.  Anyway you could post the appended version so I can dig into what I am doing wrong? I am receiving     todo = collections.deque()
NameError: name 'collections' is not defined

Comment: oops.. forgot a line. that should work now

Comment: After the addition of import collections I am receiving the following:  for line in csvrdr:
_csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?

Comment: ok, change to third line should fix that, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726953/open-the-file-in-universal-newline-mode-using-csv-module-django) for an explanation of what causes this.

Comment: Steven, would you be able to provide insight into the question I have posted here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/165911/using-python-to-compute-the-distance-speed-and-time-between-coordinates-lat-l