# installing rtree on windows 64 bits

Tags: rtree, oserror

I am using windows10 64 bits, my os.name is 'nt', I used pip to  install but its complaining about the spatialindex_c.dll

```
 File "C:\Users\Bachir\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-td64lrth\rtree\rtree\core.py", line 101, in <module>
   raise OSError("could not find or load spatialindex_c.dll")
 OSError: could not find or load spatialindex_c.dll
```

I downloaded rtree-0.8.2 and then run python setup.py install and i have the same message

```
PS C:\Users\Bachir\documents\Python Scripts\Rtree-0.8.2> python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 4, in <module>
import rtree
File "C:\Users\Bachir\documents\Python Scripts\Rtree-0.8.2\rtree\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .index import Rtree
File "C:\Users\Bachir\documents\Python Scripts\Rtree-0.8.2\rtree\index.py", line 6, in <module>
from . import core
File "C:\Users\Bachir\documents\Python Scripts\Rtree-0.8.2\rtree\core.py", line 101, in <module>
raise OSError("could not find or load spatialindex_c.dll")
OSError: could not find or load spatialindex_c.dll
PS C:\Users\Bachir\documents\Python Scripts\Rtree-0.8.2>
```

I donwloaded the spatialindex dll files ' libspatialindex-1.8.1-win-msvc-2010-x64-x32.zip ' . this file contain both 32  and 64 bits ,  unzip and put in the installation folder, when installing using python setuo.py install it still complaining about the spatialindex dll file

Answer (score 15):

Please, look at [How can I install pyproj into arcpy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/178257/2581)

1) the [RTree](http://toblerity.org/rtree/) module needs to be compiled with a version of [libspatialindex](http://libspatialindex.github.io/index.html#windows-builds) **installed** in the system (your computer) and not simply adding spatialindex dll  **after**
2) Windows has no compiler by default as in Linux or Mac OS X therefore you cannot install [RTree](http://toblerity.org/rtree/) with  `pip`  or `setup.py install`
3) in the *Python Package Index* page of [RTree](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Rtree/0.8.2), bellow **Download** there is specified

> Windows binaries http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#rtree

The files are Rtree-0.8.2-cp27-none-win32.whl and Rtree-0.8.2-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl

To install a whl file, download the file and

```
pip install Rtree-0.8.2-cp27-none-....whl (32 or 64)
```

Comment: Rtree-0.8.2-cp27-none-win32.whl is not supported on python34 platfom

Comment: Then you need to compile  Rtree  with a version of  libspatialindex but I cannot help you because I do not use Windows

Comment: Is it possible to include this downloaded wheel in your own package and to have pip install it from there? Right now I can't specify rtree as a dependency...

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and solved it by changing the core.py file in Rtree in

> C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\rtree\core.py

and changed this line :

```
rt = _load_library('spatialindex_c.dll', ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary)
```

by this :

```
rt = _load_library('spatialindex_c-64.dll', ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary)
```

Answer (score 0):

For users using Anaconda on Windows 64 bit machines:

Rtree plays an important role in Python GIS packages like geopandas, proj, pyproj etc.

I had same issue while importing geopandas in Jupyter notebook and I found out it was caused by RTree.

Now the solution to this particular problem:

```
OSError: could not find or load spatialindex_c-64.dll
```

Do these steps:

1. Update python in your conda environment only using `conda-forge` channel like:
   `conda install -c conda-forge python==3.7.10` . If you don't know what version of python to use just use what I used. You will see conda updates your python as `cpython`
2. Now update `rtree` again using `conda install rtree`. Don't provide any channel here.

You're done here.