# Installing python xlw and xlrd libraries for QGIS on Mac OSX with Python 2.6

Tags: python, qgis-plugins, error, mac

I am trying to use the XYtools plugin for QGIS (*because copy-paste is not working with just one of my files?!*), and I'm concerned that I actually just need to update my Python but not sure if doing so would disrupt anything. I've read all the posts on

> install python xlw and xlrd libraries

errors, but most instructions seem to be for PC or assume Python version >= 2.7.

I installed QGIS about 4 months ago on a brand new machine running Yosimite, using the `QGIS 2.12 built for Mac OS X Mountain Lion, Mavericks, Yosemite and El Capitan. Built with Qt Cocoa 4.8.` The only `Python` I can find on my machine is version 2.6.

*update: In the meantime, I installed the Quick Export plugin and this gives me (almost) what I need. The strange thing is, even this appears to leave out several (seemingly) random entries in the table. I'm not entirely positive there isn't a problem with the project, as I have no problem copy-pasting from other projects. In any case, the question still stands (potentially for other plugins).

Answer (score 4):

1) Yosemite comes with 2 versions of Python installed by default:

[image]

Python 2.7 (default), in the Terminal.app, type python and

[image]

Python 2.6, in the Terminal.app, type python2.6 and

[image]

The [Kyng Chaos QGIS version](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis) uses `/usr/bin/python`  and no other versions of Python (you can install other versions of Python if you want, 3.5 for examples)

[image]

2) To install a Python module, you need to know the Python "ecosystem", independent of the OS ("but most instructions seem to be for PC" is not relevant here.) -> look at **New** in [How can I install pyproj into arcpy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/178257/2581)

For example to install the xlrd module, go the [Python Package Index (Pypi)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd/0.9.4)  and

- Download [xlrd-0.9.4.tar.gz](https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/x/xlrd/xlrd-0.9.4.tar.gz#md5=911839f534d29fe04525ef8cd88fe865), unzip/tar and open Terminal.app in the unzipped folder then

  `python setup.py install`  (you need `sudo python setup.py install` because the folder /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages is protected)
  or
  `python2.6 setup.py` install (same)
- The new way of installing modules is

  `easy_install xlrd` (with [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools))
  or
  `pip install xlrd` (with [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip))