# Adding python module to QGIS python interpreter on mac?

Tags: qgis, python, installation, clustering, pysal

I'm on OS X El Capitan running QGIS version 2.18.2 which I installed via the Kyngchaos installers.

I'm trying to install a plugin, which requires, among other things, that Pysal needs to be installed.  However, despite installing it via pip it's still not working.

It appears that QGIS uses a different interpreter, which I get, but I can't find it or figure out how to install anything to it.

Comment: Have you checked existing Q&A such as https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181858/installing-python-xlw-and-xlrd-libraries-for-qgis-on-mac-osx-with-python-2-6?rq=1

Comment: Kyngchaos QGIS uses the standard Apple Python

Comment: I looked around for something just like what you linked to, @underdark.  Don't know why I didn't find that one.  Worked well, thnx much.

Answer (score 3):

The link to [a previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181858/installing-python-xlw-and-xlrd-libraries-for-qgis-on-mac-osx-with-python-2-6) @underdark posted in her comment pointed me in the right direction.

The only thing not detailed there is the syntax needed to pick between two different python 2 interpreters (system default which QGIS uses + one installed by homebrew which is my default).

For that case, I had to enter the path to the relevant interpreter, the '-m' flag, then my pip command.  In my case, the bash command was "/usr/bin/python -m pip install [module name]"