# python rasterio error

Tags: python, rasterio

When I am importing `RASTERIO` then i am getting an error as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import rasterio
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rasterio\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from rasterio._base import eval_window, window_shape, window_index
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

On importing FIONA i am getting error as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import fiona
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\fiona\__init__.py", line 78, in <module>
    from fiona.collection import Collection, BytesCollection, vsi_path
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\fiona\collection.py", line 7, in <module>
    from fiona.ogrext import Iterator, ItemsIterator, KeysIterator
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

While both `rasterio` and `fiona` installed successfully by pip install. please help some one i am stucked here.i am using python 2.7 and gdal1.10 and numpy1.10.2 on 32 bit

Answer (score 3):

In Windows, you cannot install rasterio an fiona wit `pip`, why ?

Because they need the compilation of many C libraries and Windows has no compiler by default as in Linux or Mac OS X (see [How can I install pyproj into arcpy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/178257/2581))

Therefore you can't install these module with setuptools , easy_install or pip   -> `DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found`.

Use the Christoph Gohlke's  compiled versions [fiona](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#fiona) and [rasterio](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#rasterio)

Comment: Can be done with pip if the [MS Visual C++ compiler for python](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=44266) is installed, but installing via Christoph Gohlke's versions is definitely easier.

Comment: i have installed MS visual C++ compiler for python even then i am getting same error. now i extracted pypi rasterio tar file as rasterio-0.27.0 and when i am installing it by python setup.py install then it is giving error as -rasterio/_base.c(263): fatal error c1083: canot open include : cpl_conv.h':no such file or directory and cl.exe failed with exit status 2

Comment: Have you installed the GAL/OGR Python module because [cpl_conv.h](http://www.gdal.org/cpl__conv_8h.html) is part of GDAL

Comment: yes i have installed gdal ogr via exe file. i resolved cpl_conv.h( and other header file problem) by copying required header file in microsoft visual C++ for python's include folder but now after cl.exe got all the header files i got a new problem thatis-  link .exe failed with exit status 1120.  and fatal error LINK1120: 42 unresolved externals

Comment: Sorry but I don't work on Windows and I cannot help you

Answer (score 2):

I'd say gene's answer works for the vast majority of the cases and I use Gohlke's wheel files quite often.  However, if you have a custom GDAL (or are just really set on doing it yourself), and you've got the MS C++ compiler, you can build rasterio from source on Windows.

One thing that might be hanging you up is that you'll probably need to specify a couple extra options in the `setup.cfg` file.  I did this:

```
[build_ext]
include_dirs=C:\path\to\gdal\include\dir
library_dirs=C:\path\to\gdal\lib\dir
libraries=gdal_i
```

Once you've done that, you should be able to run `python setup.py bdist_wheel` and then you'll have a wheel file in the `dist` directory.  From there, you can `pip install C:\path\to\wheel\file.whl`.

Answer (score 0):

You can download rasterio, fiona and GDAL wheel file based on your python version from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/. Please uninstall another GDAL version if available. Then use pip to install GDAL, rasterio and fiona respectively.