# ImportError: No module named pandas in Python window of ArcMap after installing with pip?

Tags: arcpy, installation, pandas, python-window

I have downloaded pandas from [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas/0.17.1/) site then unzipped it in site-packages and run python setup.py for installing pandas.

Pandas was installed successfully.

After that I tried importing pandas into the Python window of ArcMap and it gives me the following error.

```
>>> import pandas
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

Answer (score 7):

Pandas requires compilation. If you don't have an appropriate compiler and build dependencies installed, you'll  need to install a precompiled version.

Pandas depends on numpy. The Numpy [application binary interface (ABI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) is not [*forward compatible*](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5888) which means you can't use a version of Pandas that was compiled against a later version of numpy even though the [application programming interface (API)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) is compatible.

[Current versions](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas/0.18.0) of Pandas were compiled against numpy 1.8.1, so you can use them in ArcGIS 10.4 which requires numpy 1.9.2. This means you can use the methods described in [Gene's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/184651/2856).

However, ArcGIS 10.2 and 10.3 require numpy 1.7.1. Although the current versions of pandas are compatible with the numpy 1.7+ API, as they were compiled against numpy 1.8.1, they will not work with the numpy 1.7.1 installed by ArcGIS. If you install a newer version that was compiled against numpy 1.8.1, importing pandas will fail with the exception: [`ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17709641).

If you want to install Pandas to use with ArcGIS 10.2 and 10.3, you need to use the older [version 0.13](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas/0.13.1) that was compiled against numpy 1.7.1. This version can't be installed with pip. Instead, download the appropriate installer executable and run it manually.

And please note that upgrading numpy is dangerous and you are likely to break your ArcGIS installation if you try (unless you set up a virtualenv).

Comment: This is the medicine for arcmap indeed! thanks luke :)

Answer (score 4):

You don't install pandas with [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip), you use the classical `python setup.py install`instead (see [How can I install pyproj into arcpy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/178226/how-can-i-install-pyproj-into-arcpy/178257#178257))

If you installed it with pip the command would have been:

```
pip install pandas # automatic download and installation
```

With Windows and ArcPy, they are problems when you want to install a module with C dependencies with `setup.py install`

- pandas needs the compilation of many C libraries and Windows has no compiler by default
- pandas depends on a specific version of Numpy (Windows binaries built against NumPy 1.8.1)

Therefore you can install it with setup.py

That is why [whl-files](http://pythonwheels.com/) were created (pandas-0.17.1-cp27-none-win32.whl for example)

If you have pip ([How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows)) and whl ([Window: How do I install a Python package with a .whl file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27909082/835653)) installed

The classic Python solution is (**but it is not valid for ArcPy, look at the comments and the answer of [Luke](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/2856/luke)**) :

```
pip install pandas -> download and install the adequate whl file
```

Or download [pandas-0.17.1-cp27-none-win32.whl](https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp27/p/pandas/pandas-0.17.1-cp27-none-win32.whl#md5=a638c8c5c1d4290b92c205a9e6abc91c) or [pandas-0.17.1-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl](https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp27/p/pandas/pandas-0.17.1-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl#md5=2d2743bdb6e80e8733bb554837bf3761)  and

```
pip install pandas-0.17.1-cp27-none-win32.whl -> install the whl file
```

Comment: If using ArcGIS 10.2 or 10.3, you need precompiled pandas 0.13 which is built against numpy 1.7.1 https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas/0.13.1 or you'll get a `ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling` exception.

Comment: I don't use Windows, nor ArcPy, sorry and thanks for the  precision for ArcPy users (the version of Numpy is very old -> Numpy 1.10.x now)

Comment: Don't do it! You might end up having to reinstall ArcGIS. Follow Luke's suggestion.

Comment: Don't do what ? It is a simple observation that the version of Numpy is old and not  an incitement to install a new version (I don't know ArcPy)

Comment: @gene, my comment was in reference to your entire answer, not to your comment that the numpy version is old. Your answer will not work with an ArcGIS installation of Python. In fact, it will break the ArcGIS installation (including Python).

Comment: not very "pythonic" the ArcGIS installation of Python...

Comment: @gene Yeah, ESRI really screwed that up. With the rapid spread of scipy and pandas, ESRI's mistakes are wreaking ever more havoc.

Answer (score 1):

I have ArcGIS 10.3 and Windows 7 and this is how i installed Pandas:

1. Install pip: I followed [Installing Packages](https://packaging.python.org/installing/#requirements-for-installing-packages), under section "Install pip, setuptools, and Wheel" -> "Otherwise". So i downloaded [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py), opened windows command prompt, navigated to C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3 and typed `python C:\path\to\file\get-pip.py`
2. Install pandas: In windows command prompt i entered `python -m pip install pandas`. This installed a newer version of numpy and pandas

I can now use pandas in ArcMap python console and in imported scripts in Modelbuilder. So I did not need to specify any particular version of pandas or numpy for it to work.

Answer (score -1):

If you use PyCharm
go to: `File | Settings`

then from setting window click Project then Project Interpreter 
then add pandas package

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  There is no mention of PyCharm being used in the question, and instead the user appears to be trying to do this from the Python Window of ArcMap.