# Python with ArcGIS: import scikit-learn fails (bad numpy.dtype)

Tags: arcpy, installation, numpy, scikit-learn

I am trying to install scikit-learn 0.17.1 (current) into my Python 2.7.3 that accompanies my ArcGIS 10.2. The installation through `easy_install` goes through smoothly, but I get the following error on import:

```
>>> import sklearn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "Z:\lib\site-packages\scikit_learn-0.17.1-py2.7-win32.egg\sklearn\__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "Z:\lib\site-packages\scikit_learn-0.17.1-py2.7-win32.egg\sklearn\base.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .utils.fixes import signature
  File "Z:\lib\site-packages\scikit_learn-0.17.1-py2.7-win32.egg\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .murmurhash import murmurhash3_32
  File "numpy.pxd", line 155, in init sklearn.utils.murmurhash (sklearn\utils\murmurhash.c:5029)
ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling
```

After some googling it looks like a dependency mismatch. I have numpy 1.6.1 and scipy 0.10.0 installed, both working. No other dependencies are stated on the [installation guide for scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html). Is there something I missed along the way? How can I make the scikit-learn installation work?

Comment: Yep. The Acrgis installation of Python has some severe limitations when it comes to incorporating other libraries. See the related discussions here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/184646/10919. Please do not follow the advice of the most up-voted answer there.

Comment: II put a warning for the ArcPy users in my answer ([ImportError: No module named pandas in Python window of ArcMap after installing with pip?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/184651/2581))

Comment: Please see the following answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/36038113/246508

Answer (score 1):

Scikit-learn 0.20 was the last version to support Python 2.7 but e.g. ArcGIS 10.6 (and older versions of ArcGIS) does not support it. I found out that scikit-learn 0.18.2 is the latest version supported by ArcGIS 10.6.
I did some cycles of `pip install scikit-learn==<version>` and `pip uninstall scikit-learn` until I found the right version. Use `pip install scikit-learn==` to get the available versions and start trying them out until you find a supported Version. This approach should work, to find the appropriate version of scikit-learn for ArcGIS 10.2.