# Python new packages installation with ArcGIS interpreter?

Tags: arcpy, pycharm, scipy.spatial

I would like to introduce some functions derived from `scipy`in my code. Since I also need `arcpy`, I use the Interpreter installed inside ArcGIS, whose directory is: `(C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\python.exe)`.

My issue is that, if I try to install scipy from pycharm, I get this error:

`numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found`

and they suggest me to try again to install using the prompt command. But if I execute:

`pip install scipy`

I get the error:

`'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

I am not sure if the issue is related to the fact my interpreter is the ArcGIS one, but if yes, how can I solve the problem? Otherwise, what may the reason be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python installation of ArcGIS is not "standard"

1) you need first to install [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip)
2) then in theory you can install SciPy  but

- SciPy is not a pure Python module, it needs compilation of C files and Windows has no compiler by default.  You can try the [Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266)  or a version of Christoph Gohlke [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)
- **but a version of SciPy corresponds to a specific version of Numpy**
- If you were able to install SciPy with pip, it will also install the corresponding Numpy version and you cannnot change the Numpy version installed by ArcGIS, otherwise ... (see [ImportError: No module named pandas in Python window of ArcMap after installing with pip?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/184646/importerror-no-module-named-pandas-in-python-window-of-arcmap-after-installing/184651#184651)

> In fact, it will break the ArcGIS installation (including Python))

ArcGIS 10.4 will be shipped with SciPy already integrated, see [SciPy Integration in ArcGIS](http://www.digital-geography.com/scipy-arcgis/#.V2rVIY4h5MI))

Comment: I've always found this as a great resource for compiled (installable) python modules - http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy

Comment: unfortunately, due to 'reasons', scipy didn't make it into the 10.3.1 release. It is included in the 10.4 release.

Comment: Understood. I will try to install the new version of ArcGIS